# I can't seem to get this function to work right

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on the longest word coderbyte and last night I've tried playing around with a few things from this question - [Longest word in sentence code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127681/longest-word-in-sentence-code-not-working)

and here is my code:

```
function LongestWord(sen) {
    var sentence = sen.split(" ");
    console.log(sentence);
    var word = null;
    var longest = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<=sentence.length; i++){
      var words = sentence[i];
      console.log(words);
        if(longest<words.length){
          longest = sentence[i].length;
          word = sentence[i];
        }
    }
  // code goes here
  return word;

}

LongestWord("This is a test sentence!");
```

When I invoke the function, I get this error - I'm using jsbin to run my code before I submit it.

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at LongestWord (mezijosuxu.js:11:24)
    at mezijosuxu.js:21:1
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.5.min.js:1:13616
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.5.min.js:1:10537"
```

I'm console.logging the sentence array and words from the array when I run the for loop, but am I targeting the wrong thing in my if statement, or do I need to use a regex to strip the punctuation and non-alpha characters as well as target just each word? Do I need to have another for loop as well?

Comment: replace in for:
  
     for(var i=0;i< senetence.length;i++)

Comment: It says `mezijosuxu.js:11`. You need to check line 11.

Answer (score 0):

A custom sort would be easier just take your sentence array and use code similar to this

```
sentence.sort(function(a,b){
     return b.length-a.length;
});
```

This would be used right after you convert your sentence to an array. After this sort function is run your largest word could be found at `sentence[0]`

The documentation for the sort function can be found [on the Mozilla web documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the array is 5 and the index starts at 0, on the very last iteration the index will be 0, 1, 2, 3... 4! So the last index has to be smaller than the actual array length on the final iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++)
```

There are a couple of other ways of writing that function too. One Binvention touched on in their answer, and that's to use `sort` on the sentence array, but instead of grabbing the index you can use `pop` instead:

```
function LongestWord2(sen) {
  return sen.split(' ').sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
  }).pop();
}
```

Another perhaps more unwieldy method might use the result of a `reduce` on the array as an index on the array to get the longest word.

```
function LongestWord(sen) {
  var sentence = sen.split(' ');
  return sentence[sentence.reduce(function (p, c, i) {
    return c.length > p ? i : p;
  }, 0)];
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/fxfvm5s9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function LongestWord(sen) {
    var sentence = sen.split(" ");
    console.log(sentence);
    var word = null;
    var longest = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<sentence.length; i++){
      var words = sentence[i];
      console.log(words);
        if(longest<words.length){
          longest = sentence[i].length;
          word = sentence[i];
        }
    }
  // code goes here
  return word;

}

LongestWord("This is a test sentence!");
```

Issue happened because of <= replace with < symbol since array starts from 0

> i<=sentence.length